# Send stdin to console and compressed file

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I'm running a propietary program which generates text output.  Kind of like a logger.

```
logger
```

I'd like to both view this output on the terminal to watch the server breathe, and send it to a text file.  So normally I'd do:

```
logger | tee /tmp/log.txt
```

But these log files can become large enough to overwhelm my VMs disk space.  Instead of sending the text to an uncompressed text file, I'd like it to be compressed immediately.  So I might do:

```
logger
```

in one terminal and

```
logger | gzip > /tmp/log.gz
```

in another terminal.  But this doesn't feel very *nixy.

Is there a way I can accomplish this in one command, similar to using `tee`?  Here is what I'm going for, which obviously won't work, but maybe you'll get the idea:

```
logger | tee gzip > /tmp/log.txt
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With `ksh93`, `zsh` or `bash`:

```
logger | tee >(gzip > /tmp/log.txt.gz)
```

That uses that `ksh` feature called *process substitution*. `>(gzip > /tmp/log.txt.gz)` is *substituted* with the path of a file (typically something like `/dev/fd/something`, but that could also be a temporary *named pipe*) that refers to the writing end of a pipe. At the other (reading) end of that pipe, the shell connects the standard input of a new process (run in background) that executes the `gzip` command.

So, when `tee` writes to that *file*, it's actually feeding the data to `gzip`.

On systems with `/dev/fd/n`, you can do it manually (with any Bourne-like shell but ksh93) like:

```
{ logger | tee -a /dev/fd/3 | gzip > /tmp/log.txt.gz; } 3>&1
```

(though in that case `/dev/fd/3` refers to the original stdin which we've made available on the file descriptor 3 with `3>&1`, not to the pipe to `gzip` which here is just connected to `tee`'s stdout)

With `zsh`:

```
logger >&1 > >(gzip > /tmp/log.txt.gz)
```

That uses `zsh` *multios* feature whereby `zsh` implements a sort of `tee` internally to redirect the same output to more than one file (here the original stdout (`>&1`) and the pipe to `gzip` using process substitution again.

`logger`'s stdout  will actually be the writing end of a pipe. At the other end of the pipe is a shell process that reads it and distributes it both outputs like `tee` would.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  I don't totally get the syntax of the bash version.  Can I offer you a bribe for explaining it?  I'll pay a 50 pt bounty as soon as I can.

Comment: @JohnDibling, I'm not _that_ venal. Answer updated.

Comment: Let's not call it a bribe, then.  I'll be back in a couple of days. :) Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnDibling, You can also write the output to STDERR as follows:

    `logger | tee -a /dev/fd/2 | gzip > /tmp/log.txt.gz`

Comment: Not completely on topic but, why can't you view logs via 'logger' and gzip it via size-based logrotate rule?

Comment: @webKnjaZ, if they're not errors you should avoid sending them to stderr.

Comment: @user1293137: I could, but the whole point of this question is that I wanted to gzip them immediately.